# How can I fix exec format error on raspberry pi 4

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to compile code on the raspberry pi 4 using ubuntu server 20.04.1 LTS. I am using gcc to compile it and every time I try and run the file after it gets compiled successfully it says

```
-bash: ./out: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

When I do the file command on out I get, and I know that the ARM cpu is 64bit

```
out: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, ARM aarch64, version 1(SYSV), not stripped
```

This is the source that I am trying to run

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
     printf("Hello World!");
     return 0;
}
```

This is the gcc command I am running

```
gcc -march=native -ctest.c -oout
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a "LSB relocatable" file, which is not executable since it hasn't been linked because the `-c` in your command command `gcc -march=native -ctest.c -oout` stands for "compile and assemble only, do not link":

```
$ gcc --help
<...>
-c                       Compile and assemble, but do not link.
<...>
```

You should compile everything into an executable:

```
gcc -march=native test.c -o out
```